How to make probability based using Flutter's Random function?
I was trying to implement a gacha system using probability and show the result with a SnackBar, I have found question #61822429, and tried using it but i could'nt found the right way.
I was expecting the SnackBar to show up only at certain probability or rate, but instead it always appear at every click
Here's the code:
void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      Random random = new Random();
      // Gives a chance of 10% to get true result and 90% to get false.
      double falseProbability = 0.9;
      bool booleanResult = random.nextDouble() > falseProbability;
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
      int _intValue = random.nextInt(10); // Value is >= 0 and < 10.
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
            content: Text('$_intValue'),
            action: SnackBarAction(
              label: 'Undo',
              onPressed: () {
                // Some code to undo the change.
              },
            ),
          );
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    });
  }

PS: this _incrementCounter() function is a basic function out of the box from flutter new project like you may know already

"I was expecting the SnackBar to show up only at certain probability or rate, but instead it always appear at every click" - so why do you call ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar) unconditionally?

Put your SnackBar code in condition with booleanResult true/false.

@pskink I don't know how :(((

@DroidFlutter I don't think you can actually put probability that way

with if statement?

if (random.nextDouble() > falseProbability) {show your snackbar}
